# std::make_tuple doesn't make references

Tags: c++, reference, tuples, c++11

I've been experimenting with `std::tuple` in combination with references:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

int main() {
  int a,b;
  std::tuple<int&,int&> test(a,b);
  std::get<0>(test) = 1;
  std::get<1>(test) = 2;
  std::cout << a << ":" << b << std::endl;

  // doesn't make ref, not expected
  auto test2 = std::make_tuple(a,b);
  std::get<0>(test2) = -1;
  std::get<1>(test2) = -2;
  std::cout << a << ":" << b << std::endl;

  int &ar=a;
  int &br=b;
  // why does this not make a tuple of int& references? can we force it to notice?
  auto test3 = std::make_tuple(ar,br);
  std::get<0>(test3) = -1;
  std::get<1>(test3) = -2;
  std::cout << a << ":" << b << std::endl;
}
```

Of the three examples here the first two work as expected. The third one however does not. I was expecting the `auto` type (`test3`) to be the same as the type of `test` (i.e. `std::tuple<int&,int&>`).

It seems that `std::make_tuple` can't automatically make tuples of references. Why not? What can I do to make this the case, other than explicitly constructing something of that type myself?

(Compiler was g++ 4.4.5, [using 4.5 doesn't change it](http://ideone.com/EM7KQ))

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Try `forward_as_tuple`:

```
auto test3 = std::forward_as_tuple(ar,br);
```

Comment: @Dani: Why can't `tuple<int&, int&>` (the return type of `std::forward_as_tuple` as used above) be stored?  Fwiw, I tested the code before I posted it.

Comment: It compiles and works as expected with g++ 4.7.0 (10/10/2011 snapshot) and 4.6.1, but not with any 4.5 or earlier that I tried

Comment: You could write your own for use with 4.5 and earlier (as long as you have rvalue reference and variadic support).  It is a trivial helper function.  It takes `T&&...` as its argument and returns `tuple<T&&...>(std::forward<T>(t)...)`.

Answer (score 66):

`std::tie` preserves constness.

```
auto ref_tuple = std::tie(a,b); // decltype(ref_tuple) == std::tuple<int&, int&>
```

For `const` references, you'll either want the `std::cref` wrapper function:

```
auto cref_tuple = std::make_tuple(std::cref(a), std::cref(b));
```

Or use a simply `as_const` helper to qualify the variables before passing them off to `std::tie`:

```
template<class T>
T const& as_const(T& v){ return v; }

auto cref_tuple = std::tie(as_const(a), as_const(b));
```

Or, if you want to get fancy, write your own `ctie` (reusing `std::tie` and `as_const`):

```
template<class... Ts>
std::tuple<Ts const&...> ctie(Ts&... vs){
  return std::tie(as_const(vs)...);
}

auto cref_tuple = ctie(a, b);
```

Comment: It's worth emphasising that `std::[c]ref()` on `tuple` arguments can be mixed with arguments lacking it, to deduce a mixture of value and reference arguments. Also: C++17 can deduce template arguments from constructor expressions and so can use `std::tuple{...}` instead of `std::make_tuple(...)`, and it added an official `std::as_const()`. Anyway, good point about `std::tie()`; I tend to forget it exists, and it's far less noisy than `std::forward_as_tuple()`.

Comment: "`std::tie` makes non-`const` references." This statement is somewhat misleading. `std::tie` creates a tuple of lvalue references to its arguments. Whether these lvalue references refer to `const`-qualified types (aka `const` lvalue references) depends on the type being deduced. If `a` and `b` are declared `const`, then `std::tie` makes `const` lvalue references.

Answer (score 4):

How about:

```
auto test3 = std::make_tuple(std::ref(a),std::ref(b));
```

Comment: where does `std::ref` come from? With g++ 4.7 I'm getting "ref is not a member of std", and grep in monumentally unhelpful trying to work that one out.

Comment: Should be in `<functional>`. On MSVC2010 it seems to be dragged in by `<tuple>`

Comment: I like this answer because I think it makes something like `std::make_tuple(p1?std::ref(a):std::cref(a), p2?std::ref(b):std::cref(b))` feasible

Answer (score 3):

For the why: `make_tuple` parameters are passed by const reference (`const T&`), so if you pass `int&`, `T` matches `int`. If it deduced `T` to be `int&`, the parameter would be `const T&&`, and you'd get a compile error.

Comment: The reference collapsing rules are that `T = int&` applying to `const T&` results in `const int&`

Answer (score 0):

In C++14, you can proceed like that:

```
template<typename ...T, size_t... I>
auto make_rtuple_helper(std::tuple<T...>& t ,  std::index_sequence<I...>)
-> std::tuple<T&...>
{ return std::tie(std::get<I>(t)...) ;}

template<typename ...T>
std::tuple<T&...> make_rtuple( std::tuple<T...>& t )
{
    return make_rtuple_helper( t, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(T)>{});
}
```

See the how it works here in coliru : http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a665130e17fd8bcc

Cheers
A.A.

Answer (score -2):

What about `std::make_tuple<int&, int&>(a, b);`

Admittedly, it kind of defeats the purpose, but for functions like `make_shared` you still get benefits.

Warning, I haven't tried to compile this, but I believe it will work.

Comment: The idea was to avoid ever specifying the types explicitly because it's a lot more cumbersome to do in the real code

Comment: @awoodland Yeah, my answer kind of sucks.  But I didn't know about std::forward_as_tuple before.  That looks like the correct answer to me.

Comment: `make_tuple()` exists to deduce the types. If you could/wanted to specify them explicitly, there would be no point using `make_tuple`, and you should just invoke the constructor directly.