# why does make_tuple remove reference of type of args?

Tags: c++, reference

See implementation of make_tuple in std library

```
      // NB: DR 705.
  template<typename... _Elements>
    constexpr tuple<typename __decay_and_strip<_Elements>::__type...>
    make_tuple(_Elements&&... __args)
    {
      typedef tuple<typename __decay_and_strip<_Elements>::__type...>
    __result_type;
      return __result_type(std::forward<_Elements>(__args)...);
    }
```

The return type is decayed (reference removed)? so why it that ? what is the concern of this design ?

I know we have some alternative ways to achieve my requirements, e.g. boost::ref.

My question is why make_tuple has to remove the reference of types of input?

Update:
Can anyone help on this discussion of my question ?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7867220/stdmake-tuple-doesnt-make-references

Comment: @JustRufus Thank you, but my question is why we have to remove the reference of the type inside make_tuple, I know there are some alternative ways to handle my case mentioned in that post, but that it not what I want to ask.

Answer (score 0):

I was curious and reading up on this as well and I found this - I believe this is what you're looking for (see section 1 in the linked paper):
https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n2069.html
(Note: [std::pair](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair) is a specific case of a std::tuple with two elements.)

TLDR: Arrays are not constructible with `T()` and not copy-constructible. Before decay was implemented in `std::make_pair`, it was not possible to have an efficient version of `std::make_pair`.

If anyone is wondering how should you build a tuple, consult this

> In summary, when you need to build a tuple, use:
>
> `std::make_tuple` if you need values in the returned tuple,
>
> `std::tie` if you need lvalue references in the returned tuple,
>
> `std::forward_as_tuple` if you need to keep the types of references of the inputs to build the tuple.
>
> -- [Fluent C++](https://www.fluentcpp.com/2020/10/16/tie-make_tuple-forward_as_tuple-how-to-build-a-tuple-in-cpp/)