# How to return multiple values (vector and one int value) through function

Tags: c++14, c++17

I am finding connected components of a graph.
*Condition :* Those components should not be printed in same function, but they should be printed in calling function ( i.e. int main() )

I have gone through the link but got some error. 
[Returning multiple values from a C++ function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321068/returning-multiple-values-from-a-c-function)

```
  tuple <vector<int>&, int > connected( vector<int>& store, ...)        

  {
       int component_size = 0;

      // code          

       return make_tuple ( store, component_size);
  }

   int main()
   {
       // code 

       for( int i = 0 ; i < V; i++ )
           {
              if( !visited[i])
                 {
                     tie( ans, compo_size ) =  connected(edges, 
                          visited, myQ, store, V, i);

                     for(int i = 0 ; i < compo_size; i++ )
                         {
                             cout<< ans[i] <<" ";
                         }
                 }
           }
   }
```

There are few errors :

```
error: could not convert 'std::make_tuple(_Elements&& ...) [with _Elements = {std::vector >&, int&}](component_size)' from 'std::tuple >, int>' to 'std::tuple >&, int>'
         return make_tuple ( store, component_size);    
                       ^ 
error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'std::vector&' from expression of type 'std::vector'
          tie( ans, compo_size ) =  connected(edges, visited, myQ, store, V, i);
```

Comment: Your error messages are missing some characters.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7867220/560648?

Comment: Have you tried to pass-by-reference the vector and int as parameters to the function which then returns void?

Comment: Lightness Races in Orbit is right, your first error is missing some info because you had the `<` character which is viewed as a tag opening if not indented... So the stackoverflow XSS filter removed some data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to return multiple values (vector and one int value) through function

A function can have at most one return value.

Returning more objects can be emulated by either

- modifying one or more objects that are global or are referenced by arguments through indirection or by
- returning an object of class type that has multiple sub objects.

---

You've attempted the latter approach through the use of tuple class template. The reason it doesn't work is explained in the documentation:

> ```
> template< class... Types >
> tuple<VTypes...> make_tuple( Types&&... args );
> ```
>
> For each `Ti` in `Types...`, the corresponding type `Vi` in `VTypes...` is `std::decay<Ti>::type` unless application of `std::decay` results in `std::reference_wrapper<X>` for some type `X`, in which case the deduced type is `X&`.

As such, your invocation of make_tuple is deduced to return `tuple <vector<int>, int >` which is wrong because the function is supposed to return `tuple <vector<int>&, int >` instead. This can be fixed using `std::ref` so that the correct  type is deduced:

```
std::make_tuple(std::ref(store), component_size);
```

Answer (score 1):

As eerorika mentioned, you could use `std::ref()` as follow:

```
std::tuple <std::vector<int>&, int > connected( std::vector<int>& store, ...)
{
   int component_size = 0;

   // code

   return std::make_tuple ( std::ref(store), component_size);
}
```

However, there is really no point in returning a reference to the input vector since it is already a non-const reference on input. So changing the vector in place is going to be enough. On return you get a modified version. However, that's probably not what you are looking to do (i.e. you probably wanted to make a copy of `store` and return the copy with the other arrays appended...)

That also means you're going to have yet another copy when you create the tuple:

```
std::tuple <std::vector<int>, int > connected( std::vector<int>& store, ...)
{
   int component_size = 0;

   std::vector<int> result;

   // or maybe a straight copy, depends on your needs in "code"
   //std::vector<int> result(store);

   // code

   return std::make_tuple ( result, component_size);
}
```

As mentioned by others, having a result in the list of arguments is probably your best bet:

```
int connected( std::vector<int> & result, std::vector<int> const & store, ...)
{
   int component_size = 0;

   // code

   return component_size;
}
```

Also, wouldn't `component_size == result.size()` be true? If so, you should not return anything because it's going to be more confusing.

That simplifies the function to this point:

```
void connected( std::vector<int> & result, std::vector<int> const & store, ...)
{
   // code
}
```